# Automatically select taxonomy based on post meta

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I create a custom post type using jetengine name `listing` for ecommerce website review and it has post meta `platform` a dropdown select box.

This post type have taxonomy called `payment method` & `shipping method` with several terms

So when I create new post is it possible if I select `platform` A then it'll automatically select multiple terms (checkbox) in `payment method` and `shipping method`?

- if platform is A then the payment method is bank transfer, paypal and shipping method is ups, fedex
- if platform is B then the payment method is paypal, credit card and shipping method is usps, dhl, fedex

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can hook into the save_post filter to add the terms you need using php. see: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

You need to fill $data_array with your data and change the taxonomy slug to your

```
add_action( 'save_post_listing', 'listing_save_payment_term' );
function listing_save_payment_term($post_id) {

       $data_array = array(
       "platform_name" => "payment method & shipping method terms_ids comma separated in array",
       "platform_name2" => array( 15,12,18),
       "platform_name3" => array( 19,18),
       "platform_name4" => array( 19,18),
       );
       
        remove_action( 'save_post_listing', 'listing_save_payment_term' );

        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, "platform", true);
        
        
        if($meta != "") {           
        
        $platform_term_ids = $data_array[$meta];
        if($platform_term_ids != "") {
            
        //change here for your payment method & shipping method taxonomy slug
        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $platform_term_ids, 'payment method & shipping method slug');
        }
        clean_post_cache( $post_id );
        
        } else {
            
        //change here for your payment method & shipping method taxonomy slug
        wp_delete_object_term_relationships( $post_id, 'payment method & shipping method slug' );
        
        }
        
        
        add_action( 'save_post_listing', 'listing_save_payment_term' );
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks before for your reply, i'm updating my 'platfrom' from post meta into taxonomy, can this code work for taxonomy also?

Comment: Yes this code work for taxonomy, you need to change 'payment method & shipping method slug' to your taxonomy slug